# Sharepoint Designer 'All files' missing

Tags: sharepoint-designer

**The problem:** I dont see 'All files' in Sharepoint Designer:'

I have full administrator rights of whole Sharepoint.

When I open:

```
mySPwebsite.com/teams/sandbox/Gedeelde%20%20documenten/Forms/
```

I do see the All files option.

But, when I open:

```
mySPwebsite.com/teams/Bedrijfsvoering/Verkoop/Documenten/Forms/
```

I don't see the All files option.

What is going on?

Thank you!

Comment: I might be using the wrong terms, at the web application level, I have 'enabled managing of the Web Site URL Structure' enabled in central admin, when I connect to this site 'All files' shows up, however within this same web application I have multiple site collections that when I connect to, open new windows of SharePoint Designer, these site collections are missing the 'All files' options. How do I get 'All Files' to show up?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution is simple:

When you enable SharePoint Designer at the web app level (by selecting the first checkbox to Enable SharePoint Designer), if you want the user to see the All Files menu item, make sure to also check the checkbox for Enable Managing of the Web Site URL Structure.

`In central administration -> Select Web Application -->General Application Settings  -> Sharepoint Designer`

click on the `Sharepoint Designer Settings` option.

Comment: Hi Sam, you again :) " when you enable SPDesigner at the web app level " where is this option?

Comment: Please check my edited answer.

Comment: This? http://imgur.com/a/HmL4G

Comment: Yes, Select last one option and check please.

Comment: ITS WORKING! :)

Comment: Enjoy with Designer :D

Comment: its not visible for me, when i opened the site - sharepoint online site - in my SP D 2013

Comment: this works. Thumps up

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Samir's answer, you can also enable the "All Files" option by doing the following:

1. Open your site in SharePoint Designer 2013.
2. Click **Site Options** on the ribbon.
3. Change the value of **showurlstructure** to 1.

[image]